# How do I attached a video in my C# WIndows Form?

Tags: c#

Masters,

I want to know how to put a video in my Windows C# form. I want it to pop up a new form that plays a video. When a user clicks the button, the pop-up video form will pop up and play its video.

Answer (score 3):

You can use windows media player activex to play movies in c#. Just add it to toolbox (it is in Com components tab), drag it to the form and start using it.

Comment: Where can I find that the comcomponents tab? I can't seem to locate that.

Comment: Right Click in the Toolbox, Select Add Items.  Then Select the COM Components Tab.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on Windows to play the video rather than embed it into your own form.  Process.Start(PathToMovie) will take care of that...